# Is it possible to move everything from system.web to system.webserver?

Tags: iis-7

I recently started using integrated mode for an IIS application instead of Classic .NET Mode. Now I have a system.web tag and an system.webserver tag. Should it be possible to move everything from system.web to system.webserver (I do not mean just copying, but having the same functionality with tags under system.webserver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The  element specifies the root element for many of the site-level and application-level configuration settings for Internet Information Services (IIS) 7 in the ApplicationHost.config file, and contains configuration elements that define the settings used by the Web server engine and modules.

is more of .net specific setting. Specifies the root element for the ASP.NET configuration section. Contains configuration elements that configure ASP.NET Web applications and control how the applications behave.